# Outlook Add-in Sender/TO/CC/BCC issue VB.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, smtp, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have having some problems with trying to get the list of other email address within an email. Currently it gets the **SenderName** just fine but once it moves on to the **To** it seems to still have the **SenderName** as the same over and over again.

```
     If _mailItem.SenderName IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim tmpResult() As String = _mailItem.SenderName.ToString.Split(";")

        For Each name In tmpResult
            result = name.Split(",")

            If result.Length > 1 Then
                employeeAlreadyThere = EIG.FindContactEmailByName(GetSenderSMTPAddress(_mailItem).Trim)

                If employeeAlreadyThere = False Then
                    Call EIG.Search(name.ToString)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

Now that works just fine as i said for the **SenderName**. However, the below code is what comes after the above code:

```
    If _mailItem.To IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim tmpResult() As String = _mailItem.To.ToString.Split(";")

        For Each name In tmpResult
            result = name.Split(",")

            If result.Length > 1 Then
                employeeAlreadyThere = EIG.FindContactEmailByName(GetSenderSMTPAddress(_mailItem).Trim)

                If employeeAlreadyThere = False Then
                    Call EIG.Search(name.ToString)
                End If
            Else
                EIG.lastFirstName = name.Trim().ToString
                EIG.emailAddress = EIG.lastFirstName.Replace("-", "_").Replace("/", "").Replace("\", "").Replace(" ", "_").Trim() & "@zzzz.com" 'DL-I/S etwBusiness => DL@zzzz.com
                Call EIG.saveImage()
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

The **GetSenderSMTPAddress(_mailItem)** code is this:

```
Private Function GetSenderSMTPAddress(ByVal mail As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    Dim PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    If mail Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException()
    End If

    If mail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
        Dim mail_sender As Outlook.AddressEntry = mail.Sender

        If mail_sender IsNot Nothing Then
            If mail_sender.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry OrElse mail_sender.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry Then
                Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = mail_sender.GetExchangeUser()

                If exchUser IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            Else
                Return TryCast(mail_sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS), String)
            End If
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Else
        Return mail.SenderEmailAddress
    End If
End Function
```

I'm passing a **Outlook.MailItem** and i know that will always produce the *SenderName* but this is where I am unsure how to go about getting the **TO, CC & BCC**.

I've tried:

```
GetSenderSMTPAddress(_mailItem.To)
```

and that throws a warning of:

> Warning   1   Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'.

So any tips on fixing this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

All the recipients are stored in MailItem.Recipients as Recipient objects. You will need to access Recipient.AddressEntry in order to get SMTP addresses for Exchange recipients.  The To, Cc and Bcc fields are only helpful for getting display names.

Also: there's no need to do a Split on SenderName; it'll always be one email address or display name.

Comment: If I do **Dim mail_sender As Outlook.AddressEntry = mail.To** instead of **Dim mail_sender As Outlook.AddressEntry = mail.Sender** it gives a Warning of *Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry'.*

Comment: That's because the To property returns a string, not an AddressEntry object.  Only Recipient.AddressEntry and MailItem.Sender returns AddressEntry objects.

Comment: Then how would i go about getting the To/CC and BCC?

Comment: Loop through the Recipients collection and check the Recipient.Name/Address/Type properties. Type will be olTo/olCC/olBCC.